# Relative file paths not working on PHP website since hosting provider moved site from Grid server to cPanel Server

Tags: php, cpanel, relative-path

I created a PHP website that worked fine on a Grid Server with Media Temple until yesterday when they migrated the site to a newer cPanel server.  The errors say that it can't find included files.

My "includes" folder has always been in the same folder as the public html folder but not inside the public html folder (which I was taught was more secure) and that's also where it is on the new server.

The error says:
Warning: require_once(./includes/initialize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/e0qgg2hi4u4i/public_html/login.php on line 2

Line 2 in the login.php file reads:

require_once("../includes/initialize.php");

This should take it up one level in the file structure (out of the public_html directory) and then into the "includes" folder but it's obviously not working.

Again, this worked fine until the site was migrated to the new server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried putting the includes folder in a couple of different locations but none seem to be working.

Comment: Provide the solution. Share knowledge with the community.